# ¿Se puede conocer si una IP está en un hosting compartido a través de PHP?

Tags: php

Conociendo la IP de una web:

¿Se puede saber a través de PHP si está alojada en un hosting compartido?
¿O listar los dominios que usan esa misma IP?

Esta web lo hace de alguna forma: https://www.dnsqueries.com/es/vecinos_servidor_web.php

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que quieres lograr con esto. Lo cierto es que la URL que muestras en fake, no hace lo que dice. Cuando entro en ella me dice que mi IP está en Rusia, y no, no estoy en Rusia. Luego pruebo la URL `google.com` y me dice que Google tiene una serie de dominios bien raros en su servidor, lo cual no me creo. Por ejemplo en tu pregunta no entiendo lo que quieres decir: *listar las IPs que usan esa misma IP*  ¿? ¿Una IP que usa otra IP?

Comment: @A.Cedano Perdona, me expresé mal, quise decir los dominios que usan la misma IP. En el caso de los hosting compartidos, varios dominios/webs pueden usar la misma IP, pues quiero saber si hay forma de obtener esos dominios que están en una IP a través de PHP.

Comment: Lo más parecido que veo en PHP es [`dns_get_record`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.dns-get-record.php). Pero no estoy seguro de que funcione en tu caso. En SO en inglés dicen que esto depende de muchos factores en el caso de hosting compartido, por ejemplo, si el hosting tiene un registro donde guarda una lista de los dominios que corren en esa IP. Además dicen que ciertos tipos de peticiones pueden ser bloqueadas por el hosting, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero como bien dices no funciona, quizás los hosting bloquean esa info.

Comment: En esta web puedes comprabar que dominios comparte una IP. https://www.dnsqueries.com/es/vecinos_servidor_web.php Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Si, por fuerza bruta.

Si un bot recorre la web asociando nombres de dominio con direcciones IP, puede hacer una búsqueda de qué dominios están en una misma IP.

De esta manera se podría determinar si un sitio web está en un hosting compartido.

Esto tiene la desventaja de que las direcciones IP pueden cambiar, y el resultado puede no ser el esperado.

También puede darse el caso de que el servidor esté oculto detrás de un proxy, por medio de servicios como el de CloudFlare.

Comment: Creo que la pregunta es bastante concreta y aporta a la comunidad

Comment: Comprendo que a los programadores les parecen más correctas las preguntas que tienen código, pero el diseño, la arquitectura y el proceso del desarrollo de software es igual de importante. En el ecosistema de Stack Exchange en inglés existe Code Golf, Software Engineering, DBA... Etc. Pero en español sólamente tenemos este foro, que sirve como catch-all para todo tipo de dudas.

Comment: Lo entiendo perfectamente, solo era una observación ;)